# Check that at least one of two lists contain a record

Tags: apex, trigger, size

I want to make sure that either my assignedOpps or updatedOpps list contains at least one value, before executing the rest of my code.

The next set of steps in the code apply to either list, before later steps only apply to one list or the other.

But when I use

```
if(reassignedOpps.size() > 0 OR UpdatedOpps.size() > 0){
```

I get an error

> expecting a right parentheses, found 'OR'

and I can't find an alternative?

```
trigger OpportunityTargetUpdate on Opportunity (after update) {

    for (Opportunity o : Trigger.new){

        //check that Opportunity record type is valid
        if(validRecordTypeIds.contains(o.RecordTypeId))
        {
            //check whether Opportunity owner has changed
            Opportunity oldOpp = Trigger.OldMap.get(o.Id);
            if(oldOpp != null
               &&
               oldOpp.OwnerId != o.OwnerId)
            {
                identifiers.add(o.Identifier__c);
                reassignedOpps.add(o);
                system.debug('reassignedOpps contains ' + reassignedOpps);
            }else
                //check whether close date month or year has changed
                if(oldOpp != null 
                   &&
                   (oldOpp.CloseDate.month() != o.CloseDate.month()
                    ||
                    oldOpp.CloseDate.year() != o.CloseDate.year()
                   )){
                       identifiers.add(o.Identifier__c);
                       updatedOpps.add(o);
                       system.debug('updatedOpps contains ' + updatedOpps);
                   }
        }else{
            system.debug('No Opportunities with a valid Record Type Id were found');
        }
        if(reassignedOpps.isEmpty() == true){
            System.debug('no Opportunities had new owners');
        }
        if(updatedOpps.isEmpty() == true){
            System.debug('no Opportunities had a close date with a new month or year');
        }
        system.debug('identifiers contains ' + identifiers);
    }

    if(reassignedOpps.size() > 0 OR UpdatedOpps.size() > 0){
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `OR` operator in apex to perform a logical OR operation. You will have to use the double pipe `||` for that (and its already being used in your code `(oldOpp.CloseDate.month() != o.CloseDate.month() || oldOpp.CloseDate.year() != o.CloseDate.year())`).

YOu can check it out [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm) for more details ;

You can use `OR` in formulas and in SOQL queries.